# Globbing with ls to find all files matching a certain pattern

Tags: glob, ls

I'm trying to locate all PDF files in some folder and any subfolder, just in the terminal, as opposed to in a script. I'm also quite new to linux, so apologise if I've missed anything obvious, or perhaps vital to diagnosing my particular problem.

I'm using bash 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu), and have done some poking about on google about glob and extglob expressions, and it appears the syntax I should be using is

```
$ ls **.pdf
```

This however finds nothing, since there is no file matching the pattern `*.pdf` in the current folder `./`; it appears to want to read `**` as `*`:

```
ls: cannot access **.pdf: No such file or directory
```

There are PDFs elsewhere, in subfolders between 1 and 5 deep (in particular in *every* subfolder 1-deep), some of which I can see by checking with

```
$ ls */*.pdf
```

Hence, `ls` appears to be working properly. Its manual appears to not be very helpful, since all I could see that might be of any use us calling `ls` with the `-R` flag, which does not solve the problem in any of the above cases.

I tried using extglob patterns (making sure to turn them on with `shopt`). I can see my depth-1 files with `ls */*?(.)pdf`, but I can't see anything with `ls .*(/*)pdf` or `ls .*(/*).pdf`, even from within a subdirectory where there are PDFs.

I've read elsewhere (in reference to the `.gitignore` file in a git repository) that the `**` pattern does not work for everyone.

Could this be affecting me, and how might I remedy it (ideally without superuser privileges)? Might this (or some related problem) be also affecting the extglob functionality?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may want to consider find

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec ls -l {} \;
```

or

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -ls
```

where . is your current working directory. The glob functionality comes with 4.0+ bash.   The glob extensions are not portable in other words.

Comment: By "glob extensions" do you mean `extglob` shell option? Is it honored by `find`?

Answer (score 7):

The options `extglob` and `globstar` are required to get the extended functionality from the `glob` library; they are turned on using the shell options (`shopt`) utility as described below.

To use the `globstar` (which causes the `**` pattern to behave as described in the bash manual) one must activate it (in bash 4.0+) with

```
shopt -s globstar
```

and to enable the more "functional" regex-type expressions like `?(ab)` and `*(ab)` their full effect, use

```
shopt -s extglob
```

To turn the options off again, specify the `-u` flag instead of `s`, for eaxample

```
shopt -u globstar
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe `echo **/*.pdf` is what you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).